# Python cron - ValueError: improper number of cron entries specified; got 1 need 5 to 7

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I have the error:

> ValueError: improper number of cron entries specified; got 1 need 5 to
> 7

I'm using Python 3, and this is my code:

```py
def add_cron():
    cron = CronTab(getpass.getuser()) # For current user
    basic_command = "*/15 * * * * python3 /opt/yesiam.py"
    basic_iter = cron.find_command("yesiam")
    exists=False
    for item in basic_iter:
        if str(item) == basic_command:
            print("crontab job already exist", item)
            exists=True
            break

    if not exists:
        job = cron.new(command='python3 /opt/yesiam.py')
        job.minute.every(15)
        job.enable()
        cron.write()
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a completely different package. Its an easy mistake to make, seeing as how they have such similar names.

That error message is coming from the [`crontab`](https://pypi.org/project/crontab/) package.

Installed using:

```
pip install crontab
```

You want instead the [`python-crontab`](https://pypi.org/project/python-crontab/) package.

Installed using:

```
pip install python-crontab
```

They are distinct projects, maintained by different people. Check out the open-source repositories here:

- For the `python-crontab` package: https://gitlab.com/doctormo/python-crontab/
- For the `crontab` package: https://github.com/josiahcarlson/parse-crontab

Consider using [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) to prevent any conflicts you may have with other projects using conflicting packages and versions.